# Recover data containing "<" and ">"

Tags: xml, xslt

I wish I could edit an XML file with an XSL file. The problem is that there are "<" and ">" in the data and it understands it as tags while that is data.

I tried with `<xsl: value-of select = "translate (node (), '&lt;', '*')" />` to remove the "<" and try to return it afterwards, but it does not work.

My INPUT XML:

```
<text name="LEVEL1" >
    <p name="AS">Dear Sir/Madam</p>
    <p name="AS"><new-line/>Batman<new-line/>Superman</p>
</text>
```

What I want in OUTPUT :

```
    <LEVEL1>
        <AS>Dear Sir/Madam</AS>
        <AS><new-line/>Batman<new-line/>Superman</AS>
    </LEVEL1>
```

My XSL :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="text">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
            <xsl:element name="{@name}">
                <xsl:for-each select="child::p">
                    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
                        <xsl:value-of select= "node()"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I have actually :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LEVEL1>
   <AS>Dear Sir/Madam</AS>
   <AS>
    </AS>
</LEVEL1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, there are no "<" and ">" in the data. You are looking at the lexical version of the XML, but when processed by an XML parser, the `<new-line/>` to which you are referring becomes an element. So, the question is how to retain the elements in your output. You are currently losing it because of your use of `xsl:value-of` which just returns the text value of an element. What you really need to use is `xsl:apply-templates`.

This looks like a follow-up to your previous question. What your first need is template that matches elements with a `name` attribute, so you can transform them

```
<xsl:template match="*[@name]">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

For other elements, like `<new-line />`, you can use the identity template.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Putting it all together, gives this...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="*[@name]">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am beginning to understand the concept of the apply-template thanks to you, thank you very much!